# Handlebars form handling

Tags: forms, handlebars.js

My nodejs app has a handlebars page with to forms separated in two partials. The first works perfectly OK, but the second form unexpectedly logs the user out after submission. Besides, once the submission is done it redirects to the login page as indicated by the passportjs middleware I've configured in case the use has not loged in. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? Please!

At first I put the two forms on the page, when I noticed this I decided to split them but this didn't solve the problem. Second, I thought maybe the route itself was conflicting with some other routes so I created a separate route file. And yet it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no form handling done by Handlebars. The handling of form data is done by your Node.js app. You must share code in for people to diagnose the issue you are experiencing.